# Django Forms Integrity Error

Tags: django, forms

I created a project with Django and am trying to write from forms to db.
The model class has two classes :

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    birth_day = models.DateTimeField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    PHONETYPE_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Home'),
        (1, 'Work'),
        (2, 'Fax'),
        (3, 'Mobile'),
        (4, 'Other'),
    )
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    phone_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=PHONETYPE_CHOICES)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Now if I want to write to this with forms and I use only:

Name

Birthday

Address

Number type

Phone Number

as form fields.

I get:

IntegrityError x_phonenumber.contact_id may not be NULL

This is part of the view:

```
def main(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name'],
            birth_day = form.cleaned_data['birth_day'],
            address = form.cleaned_data['address'],
#            contact1= form.cleaned_data['id']
            phone_type = form.cleaned_data['phone_type']
            phonenumber = form.cleaned_data['phonenumber']
            contact = Contact(
                name = form.cleaned_data['name'],
                birth_day = form.cleaned_data['birth_day'],
                address = form.cleaned_data['address'],
            )
            contact.save()
            number = PhoneNumber(
#                contact1 = form.cleaned_data ['id']
                phone_type = form.cleaned_data['phone_type'],
                phonenumber = form.cleaned_data['phonenumber'],

            )
            number.save()
```

I know I have to fill in the ID of the person in that ForeignKey, but I thought that is what the ForeignKey will do for me.

The two commented out object "contact1" did not work. But that is basically what I want, add the id to this.

Also, Django always adds an _id primary key to every table (contact and Phonenumber).

So i did not get why, Django did not add to this.

How can I save this to db with the correct id, primary key etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ForeignKey can't magically know which person it's supposed to be pointing at, unless you tell it.

In your case, once you've done `contact.save()`, you now *have* a Contact instance, so you can use that.

```
number = PhoneNumber(
    contact = contact,
    phone_type = form.cleaned_data['phone_type'],
    phonenumber = form.cleaned_data['phonenumber'],
)
number.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider these two lines:

```
number = PhoneNumber(
    #   contact1 = form.cleaned_data ['id']
    phone_type = form.cleaned_data['phone_type'],
    phonenumber = form.cleaned_data['phonenumber'],
)

number.save()
```

You are creating an instance of `PhoneNumber` and saving it. However any instance of `PhoneNumber` is required to have a valid foreign key to  an instance of `Contact`. This is not being set before you `save()` the `PhoneNumber` and hence you get the error.

In order to solve this, point the `contact` field of the `PhoneNumber` instance to the `Contact` you saved before you save the phone number. Something like this:

```
number = PhoneNumber(
    #   contact1 = form.cleaned_data ['id']
    phone_type = form.cleaned_data['phone_type'],
    phonenumber = form.cleaned_data['phonenumber'],
)

number.contact = contact # <===== Attach the contact.
number.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

How could Django know wich rows should it chain?
You have to pass contact instance as argument for foreign key field.

```
contact = Contact(...)
contact.save()
number = PhoneNumber(...)
number.contact = contact # here comes the instance of Contact model
number.save()
```